# Using Cytoscape.js how do I access a data field that has a colon in its key?

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

Having followed the [official documentation](https://js.cytoscape.org/) and [tutorial](https://blog.js.cytoscape.org/2016/05/24/getting-started/), I am able to -- as long as the key is a simple string -- access a node's data field and use it for a node label.

However, my data will have fields with a colon in its keys (see code snippet for an example). How can I make this example work, expecting to see 'aa' and 'bb' as node labels?

I know that "data(id)" for the style label attribute works for the id field and tried several alterations using single/double quotes, single/doubles quotes around the key, bracket notation, etc., but that all didn't help.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cytoscape/3.21.2/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <style>
    #cy {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
    }
  </style>

  <body>
    <div id="cy"></div>
    <script>
      var cy = cytoscape({
        container: document.getElementById("cy"),
        elements: [
          { data: { "id": "a", "skos:prefLabel": "aa" } },
          { data: { "id": "b", "skos:prefLabel": "bb" } },
          { data: {
              id: "ab",
              source: "a",
              target: "b",
            },
          },
        ],
        style: [
          {
            selector: "node",
            style: {
              "shape": "square",
              "background-color": "red",
              "label": "data(skos:prefLabel)" /* What do I put here? I know that replacing this 
                                                 with "data(id)" works for the id field, but I 
                                                 need it to work for the skos:prefLabel field, 
                                                 expecting 'aa' and 'bb' */
            },
          },
        ],
      });
      
      console.log(cy._private.elements[1]._private.data["skos:prefLabel"]); /*  I can see the data 
                                                                                is there and I 
                                                                                can access it 
                                                                                using standard 
                                                                                javascript. */
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve my own problem, inspired by an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65024627/multiple-data-values-for-label-text-in-cytoscape-js).

Using a function, I was able to access the field with a colon in its key:

```
// compare with code above

style: [
          {
            selector: "node",
            style: {
              "shape": "square",
              "background-color": "red",
              "label": (element) => element.data("skos:prefLabel"), /* this resulted 
                                                                    in showing 'aa' 
                                                                    and 'bb' as node 
                                                                    labels. /*
            },
```

See also working codepen [here](https://codepen.io/amirwesthoff/pen/zYWrzJw).